# NSWindow Title bar customizations

Tags: macos, cocoa, alignment, nswindow, titlebar

I would like to design a NSWindow title bar like the following screenshot,

[image]
This is a screen shot of GitHub mac application.Please see the horizontal alignment of windows default Close,minimize and maximize buttons.Those are horizontally aligned with the other buttons like repositories and others.

How Can I achieve the same in my application.I have tried using NSThemeFrame but I can not change the frames of this buttons.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [custom window](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) to achieve that effect.